# Ionic 3 - sort month with year and set the title

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am having list of objects in which each object contains date string value like October 2018, March 2012 etc.

I want to sort this date string values more over while display in the list view, the list view header should display each month and year as title as one time for that month.

For example see the image below.
[image]

Thanks
krish

Comment: I believe an ion-grid would do the job for you. It will allow you to set the values in a nicer format.

Comment: My question is how to do date calculation and display in each headers?

Answer (score 0):

I got it how to solve this. See the code below.

```
   let currentMonth: string = '';
    let sortedList = [];
  for (let item of list) {
      let title_date = moment(item.getCreatedDate(), "DD-MM-YYYY").format("MMM YYYY");
      if (currentMonth != title_date) {
        currentMonth = title_date;
        item.setTitleDate(title_date);
      }
      else {
        item.setTitleDate('');
      }
      sortedList.push(item);
```